# Project Euler #3 Ruby

Tags: ruby

The task:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>   What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

The correct answer is `6857`.

My code:

```
def prime?(n)
  (2..(n-1)).each { |x| false if n % x == 0 }
  true
end

x = 2
prime_factor_arr = []
number = 600_851_475_143

while x < number
  if number % x == 0 && prime?(x)
    prime_factor_arr << x
    number = number / x
  end
  x += 1
end 

puts prime_factor_arr.last
puts prime?(prime_factor_arr.last)
puts prime_factor_arr
```

In the above case, I get `1471` as the largest prime. If I change the code to:

```
while x < (number / x)
  if number % x == 0 && prime?(x)
    prime_factor_arr << x
  end
  x += 1
end
```

I get `486847`. The array printed in the end is:

```
[71, 839, 1471, 6857, 59569, 104441, 486847]
```

It is not clear to me why my code does not work. Could anybody help?

Comment: Do you realize that your `prime?` returns `true` for _all_ numbers?

Comment: Not a ruby expert, but it looks like your `prime?` function always returns true.  486847, for example, is not prime.

Comment: THANK YOU! Ok, I have just added `return false` instead of just `false` and it worked. Do I  understand correctly, that I need to specifically type in `return` if I wish the method to exit, right?

Comment: @AleksGorbenko: basically, yes (if current expression is not the last expression, in which case you can omit the `return`)

Comment: back in the days, programming homework needed to be solved without the  help of others.. ;)

Comment: Or at least without the internet.  Nothing wrong with pair programming.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the question, Sergio is right. But the code Sergio suggests (as well as yours) will not work correctly when `number` is a prime itself.

A better way to write is:

```
def prime?(n); (2...n).none?{|x| n.%(x).zero?} end

number = 600_851_475_143

number.downto(1).find{|x| number.%(x).zero? and prime?(x)}
```

Comment: Oh come on, `n.%(x).zero?` is borderline ugly :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I thought you were going to say that. But not for me.

Comment: yeah, your answer will also be faster too. I only fixed the `prime?`, didn't check the rest.

Comment: As a further opto, skip all even numbers :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I had made a huge mistake. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def prime? n
    (2..(n-1)).each { |x| return false if n % x == 0 }
    true
end

n = 600_851_475_143
a = []
product_sum = 1
x = 2 # 2 is the first prime number

while product_sum < n
    if n % x == 0 && prime?(x) 
        a << x
        product_sum *= x
    end
    x += 1
end

puts "The answer is #{a.last}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The prime lib (from standard lib) is very nice for Project Euler. But it takes the fun out of this one:

```
require "prime"
600851475143.prime_division.last.first # => 6857
```